# xui supports private browsing for iOS safari devices?

Tags: javascript, ios, private, xui

I have a website that is using xui.js

When turning on Private Browsing mode on an iPhone iOS5+, the xui.ready function does not get called.  Is there a fix for it?

```
<script>   
  alert('test');   
  xui.ready(function (e) {
    alert('test2');
  });
</script>
```

No Private mode you see both 'test' and 'test2'
In Private mode you see only 'test'

When browsing with a safari desktop it works fine with private mode on, seems to only happen on iOS devices such as iphones and ipods.

Comment: What is the content of xui.ready? Cuz that code itself is not the problem. All you do is pass a function to another function.

Comment: There is a lot of javascript and functions that run in the xui.ready that are not running when in private mode, which basically needs to run for the website to work.